# signalR hub is taking too much time to load

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Retrieval of /signalr/hubs gets very slow after 5-10 minutes, I've to restart app pool again and again. Is there any way to cache this?

What I've done-

1. Checked all the memory and cpu allocations for App pool but couldn't
   find anything.
2. Searched on google but didn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 3):

You can try putting this jquery functions in you View Page.

```
var tryingToReconnect = false;

$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = true;
});

$.connection.hub.reconnected(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = false;
});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
    if(tryingToReconnect) {
        notifyUserOfDisconnect(); // Your function to notify user.
    }
});
```

Also check if you network connection is slow.

```
$.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function() {
    notifyUserOfConnectionProblem(); // Your function to notify user.
});
```

You'll get exact idea about the problem weather issue is because of `signalR` or not.
Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but my problem is diff. when this  /signalr/hubs url is hit and it generates a javascript that is taking time and not the connection.

Comment: yes i got your point but hitting `/signalr/hubs` is the actual connection with your hub. you can check this with the above given functions. I faced similar issue and got solution From this. You can still refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) for better understanding.

Comment: When page doesn't even load and waits for hubs script, How can I run js?

Comment: Hub's Script will be fired from some page only when it will be initialized in a page. right? In the Same page you can write this code.

Comment: Lets consider this example <script src='http://ss/signalr/hubs'/> // Here I need to perform some steps but the execution would not reach here